# Strong encryption for a local file (PGP)

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg, smartcard, yubikey

*Just a quick disclaimer: I initially posted this question to Crypto site but was told it was too specific for that site.*

I am looking for a safe method to encrypt a local file on my machine. Let's say I have a file containing my logins and passwords -- how can I make sure that the encryption is reasonably sufficient in case this file falls into the wrong hands? I have a Yubikey that supports PGP application, and on it, I have a signature, encryption, and authentication PGP subkeys. I would like to find a protocol that would protect the file even when someone may get the encrypted file AND the USB token.

Ideally, I would like to find a protocol that would not require a specific program/script to create such encryption. The first thing that came to mind is to encrypt it with a symmetric key using PGP (GPG) and then encrypt the output using my own PGP public key. I know I should not invent the wheel when it comes to cryptography; hence, I am looking for established protocols or the combination thereof that have been tested with time and have all their shortcomings well known.

I am aware of password manager apps, but most of them cannot be used offline. The one that can (KeePass2) is a PITA to set up for a 2FA with Yubikey, especially on Linux which is my primary OS. Any alternative?

Comment: Am I right, that you're trying to find an algorithm/mechanism for securing? Should it be decryptable, by a key? If yes, I suggest to use RSA.

Comment: Why not just configure your PGP key with a complex passphrase that's a minimum of 16characters long and includes at least 2 each of the following: lowercase, uppercase, numbers, and symbols?

Comment: @rktech, yes, it should be decryptable by a key since I want to use the Yubikey's OpenPGP app. My key pair is already in RSA format (4096-bit), so that part is covered.

Comment: @JW0914, that would be a good way to increase security, but Yubikey only supports numerical pin when it comes to its OpenPGP app. Hence, I was thinking to encrypt it twice: using symmetric key (user password) and asymmetric key pair (hardware token). If I use my own script, I can marginally increase security by padding the password and hashing it, but I'm not sure if it would be worth the effort.

Comment: Create a PGP key via `gpg` directly, then transfer the key to the YubiKey.  To do this sanely, create the primary key w/ the ability to _only_ Sign & Certify [SC], protecting the main key with a complex passphrase in line with the above, then add separate RSA subkeys, _one each_, for Signature, Encryption, and Authentication [S, E, and A].  Next, export the secret keys of the main, then export each subkey secret key individually, protecting each as above _(the exports are vital)_.  Once the secret keys of the primary & all subkeys have been exported, transfer just the 3 subkeys to the YubiKey

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide) will walk you through how to this manually via `gpg`, however, deviate from the author's instructions regarding what abilities each key should have so they're in line with my last comment.  The master key should only ever be used to Sign and Certify subkeys and **_not_** be used for any other purpose, as subkeys are easy to revoke, but it's a PIA to have to revoke the master, as it revokes all subkeys under it, creating an enormous inconvenience with potentially disastrous consequences.